# android webview html input type color

Tags: android, html, cordova, webview

I have this simple html form:

```
  <form>
   <input type="color" id="myID"/>
  </form>
```

And works fine in Android Chrome. My problem is that when I put this code in a webview and click on the color, the colorpicker does not open and the application crashes. I've tried building the app using cordova too but the application crashes in the same way.

I have not seen any error in the log cat. Any idea?

EDIT

I've test with my Nexus 7 - Android 5.0.1 and crash.

This is my code to load the html content:

```
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
myWebView.clearCache(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);


if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    myWebView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
}
else {
    Log.e("XXXX", "ERROR. API < 16");
}


myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

    public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {
        Log.e("XXXX", cm.message() + " -- From line "
                + cm.lineNumber() + " of "
                + cm.sourceId() );
        return true;
    }

});

myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

And I obtain this error:

Error inflating class com.android.org.chromium.ui.ColorPickerAdvanced

Comment: Not using Cordova but a WebView in a 'normal' Android app your code works for me for Android versions above 4.4.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I met the same problem too. But after updating the web view to 50.0(20 Apr 16), this version solved the problem and my Cordova app would not crash when using html5 color picker.